# Could not find "api_controller.rb" in any of your source paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to create a Rails 5 api app using http://alessiofanelli.com/blog/building-a-rails-5-and-ember-js-app.

I get the

> could not find api_controller.rb

error while executing the scaffold command as below.

```
$ rails g scaffold team name:string city:string championships:integer
```

> Running via Spring preloader in process 32480 invoke active_record
>   identical db/migrate/20160204101609_create_teams.rb identical
>   app/models/team.rb invoke test_unit identical test/models/team_test.rb
>   identical test/fixtures/teams.yml invoke resource_route route
>   resources :teams identical app/serializers/team_serializer.rb invoke
>   scaffold_controller Could not find "api_controller.rb" in any of your
>   source paths. Your current source paths are:
>   /home/kpatil/.gem/ruby/gems/active_model_serializers-0.9.4/lib/active_model/serializer/generators/serializer/templates

Which shows below message in terminal

```
$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.0.beta2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run rails server -h for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Puma 2.16.0 starting...

    Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
    Environment: development
    Listening on tcp://localhost:3000 Started POST "/teams" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-02-04 16:25:06 +0530 ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms) SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"

ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant TeamsController):
activesupport (5.0.0.beta2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in const_get' activesupport (5.0.0.beta2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:inblock in constantize'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:257:in each' activesupport (5.0.0.beta2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:257:ininject'
activesupport (5.0.0.beta2) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:257:in constantize' actionpack (5.0.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/http/request.rb:93:incontroller_class'
actionpack (5.0.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:44:in controller' actionpack (5.0.0.beta2) lib/action_dispatch/routing
```

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this?

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem that you. I fixed this issue installing:

> gem 'active_model_serializers', '~> 0.10.0.rc1'

Before, I had 0.9.4 version for this gem. Now the scaffold generator works fine.

Regards!

Comment: Thumbs up on this solution.

Comment: Is it possible to solve this without upgrading active_model_serializers?

Comment: I also don't think I'd like to upgrade from 0.9.x as there seems to be a lot of major breaking changes. Any luck on this yet?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem & figured out that this also happens if you have active admin installed.

The solution is then to add in your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.app_generators.scaffold_controller = :scaffold_controller
```